# Which thing describe the song more than melody?

Tags: terminology, melody

A melody (also tune, voice, or line) is a linear succession of musical tones that the listener perceives as a single entity.

Is there any thing better than melody?
I mean in the sense of sweet tune, voice?

Comment: Hello and welcome - and sorry, but I don't understand!  *Is there any genre better than Melody* makes no sense, because 'melody' is not a genre. Are you sure that 'genre' is the right word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the groove of the song. For example, some songs are made entirely out of percussion like for example Rebounds by Yannis Xenakis:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bXw_phbUI2g

There is no conventional melody in this song, although what defines it is it's groove.

Answer (score 2):

What defines a song greatly depends on the song. Some songs, like most fiddle tunes, are best defined by the melody. In other cases, a particular harmony defines the song better. What defines the song is really what sticks out to whoever is listening. This can be different between different people. Some songs are even so famous that *anything* can define them. For example, the main theme from *Star Wars* can be defined by the opening note, the introduction, the main melody, the B melody, the low brass part during the A melody, the percussion, or anything else you can think of. However, **in almost all cases (except the rare case of a nameless song), the name defines the song better than the melody.** This is because the name requires no musical skill to communicate.